# Measuring page load timings using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, testing, extjs

I have created a script in JavaScript that is injected into our Ext JS application during automated browser testing. The script measures the amount of time taken to load the data in our grids.

Specifically, the script polls each grid, looks to see if there is a first row or a 'no data' message, and once all grids have satisfied this condition the script records the value between Date.now() and performance.timing.fetchStart, and treats this as the time the page took to load.

This script works more or less as expected, however when compared with human measured timings (Google stopwatch ftw), the time reported by this test is consistently around 300 milliseconds longer than when measured by stopwatch.

My questions are these:

- Is there a hole in this logic that would lead to incorrect results?
- Are there any alternative and accurate ways to achieve this
  measurement?

The script is as follows:

```
function loadPoll() {
    var i, duration,
        dataRow = '.firstRow', noDataRow = '.noData',
        grids   = ['.grid1', '.grid2', '.grid3','.grid4', 'grid5', 'grid6', 'grid7'];

    for (i = 0; i < grids.length; ++i) {
            var data   = grids[i] + ' ' + dataRow,
            noData = grids[i] + ' ' + noDataRow;

        if (!(document.querySelector(data) || document.querySelector(noData))) {
            window.setTimeout(loadPoll, 100);
            return;
        }
    }

duration = Date.now() - performance.timing.fetchStart;
    window.loadTime = duration;
}

loadPoll();
```

Some considerations:

- Although I am aware that human response time can be slow, I am sure
  that the 300 millisecond inconsistency is not introduced by the human
  factor of using Google stopwatch.
- Looking at the code it might appear that the polling of multiple
  elements could lead to the 300 ms inconsistency, however when I
  change the number of elements being monitored from 7 to 1, there
  still appears to be a 300 ms surplus in the time reported by the
  automated test.
- Our automated tests are executed in a framework controlled by
  Selenium and Protractor.

Thanks in advance if you are able to provide any insight to this!

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:node.js] but the question contains code that uses `window`, `document.querySelector`. I'm removing the tag.

Answer (score 9):

If you use `performance.now()` the time should be accurate to 5 microseconds.  According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now):

> The performance.now() method returns a DOMHighResTimeStamp, measured
>   in milliseconds, accurate to five thousandths of a millisecond (5
>   microseconds).
>
> The returned value represents the time elapsed since the time origin
>   (the PerformanceTiming.navigationStart property).

Comment: Thanks, when comparing this directly against Date.now() - performance.timing.fetchStart; this seems to be about 20 milliseconds more correct, which is a step in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I would revise my approach to how the actual measuring of the time is captured. Rather than evaluating the time for each loadPoll() call, you can evaluate how many calls you can perform for a given period of time. In other words you can count the number of function iterations for a longer period of time, eg 1000 milliseconds. Here's how this can be done:

```
var timeout = 1000;
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var elapsedTime = 0;

for (var iterations = 0; elapsedTime < timeout; iterations++) {
    loadPoll();
    elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;   
}

// output the number of achieved iterations
console.log(iterations);
```

This approach will give you more consistent and accurate time estimates. Faster systems will simply achieve a greater number of iterations. Keep in mind that setInterval()/setTimeout() are not perfectly precise and for really small interval timers these functions may give you invalid results due to garbage collection, demands from events and many other things that can run in parallel while your code is being executed.